# Why float shows exact representation when declared

Tags: c#, c++, .net, floating-point

I have read many times in [articles](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/FloatingPoint.aspx) and MSDN that `float` (or `double`) doesn't have exact representation of real world integers or decimal values. Correct ! That is visible when getting equality checks going wrong or also while asserting simple addition or subtraction tests.

It is also said that float doesn't have exact representation of decimal values like 0.1, but then if we declare a float in visual studio like `float a = 0.1f;`, how do they show exact 0.1 while debugging ? It should show something like `0.09999999..`. Where do I miss a link to understand it.

[image]

It is a layman sort of question or may be I am still missing some concepts !

Comment: `0.1f` is something like `0.100000001490116119384765625`, so only on the 9th significant digit you have something != 0 after the initial `1`, and `float` only have around 7 digit precision.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> how do they show exact 0.1 while debugging

0.1 isn't the exact value of the float. It happens to be what you specified in the original assignment, but that's not the value of the float. I can see it's confusing :) I suspect the debugger is showing the shortest string representation which unambiguously ends up at the same value.

Try using:

```
float a = 0.0999999999f;
```

... and then I suspect in the debugger you'll see *that* as `0.1` as well.

So it's not that the debugger is displaying a "more exact" value - it's that it's displaying a "more generally convenient" representation.

If you want to display the *exact* value stored in a float or double, I have [some code you can use for that](http://jonskeet.uk/csharp/DoubleConverter.cs).

Comment: Thanks Jon! I was reading your article and the other article pointed out by you. I also ran DoubleConverter.cs. This all together raised this question. But now I am more clear.

Comment: Before you answered, I was also wondering what did you mean by getting  exact representation of float by writing DoubleConverter; because as in question IDE itself showed 0.1.

Comment: @NirajDoshi: Right - and my point is that 0.1 *isn't* the exact value. I'll edit the answer to make that clearer.