# Why parsing of a string with float value gives me number with big number of digits after point

Tags: c#, json.net, double

I have the following code

```
app.First.SelectToken("averageScore")?.ToString()
```

It's parsing json with the help of `Newtonsoft` library.

Here is the result

"4,8"

But when I try to cast it to double I have the following result:

"4.7999999999999998"

Code:

```
double.Parse(app.First.SelectToken("averageScore")?.ToString())
```

But I need double 4.8. How to get it? For decimal this way work nice. But I need double.

Comment: you could use decimal data type...that is fixed point...definitely wont get that problem...more overhead on the data type

Comment: Just display the double in a different format (e.g. 1 decimal place) then it will look like 4.8.

Comment: "But I need double 4.8" - I may have bad news for you... there **is** no `double` with value **exactly** 4.8

Comment: Old classic [float precission trouble](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31066521/why-float-shows-exact-representation-when-declared). Consider using decimal :-P

Comment: @Sweeper can you give me an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the same kind of problem you have when trying to representing the number `1/3` as a decimal: you can't do it precisely. In this case, the `.8` decimal value does not have an exact representation in base-2, and so you get an imperfect approximation as the result. You may do a little better using the `decimal` type, but you still need to be careful.

Comment: Thank you. Can you tell me which problems I could have with converting to decimal? Which is the best way?